# Silverlight: Set windowless to true but not in HTML/ASPX

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to find out how to set the windowless parameter to true, but not in the object tag, but directly in the Silverlight Application. I don't know if that possible, but i thought maybe this can be done in the app.xaml?

any ideas?

Christian

Comment: Can you also mention the purpose then will be helpful. Like is it for overlapping silverlight controls etc

Comment: the purpose of this is simple. we want to make this setting part of the silverlight app so we can forget about setting this in each and every html/aspx code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That parameter can not be set after the Silverlight Application has loaded. You can check the parameter with `Application.Current.Host.Settings.Windowless`, but it is a read-only property.

If you need to programmatically decide whether to set windowless mode, you will have to do it in the page that hosts the Silverlight XAP. Your best bet is probably to use a `StringBuilder` to generate the entire `<object>` tag in the code-behind of your ASPX page (or even wrap the entire object tag up as a CompositeControl) and pass an `isWindowless` bool in as a parameter.